# Objective c Facebook

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook

I am developing an application that posts in IOS Facebook wall.
I'm using SDK Facebook.

My problem is if I have installed Facebook on my iPhone, when I call the permissions, it calls the Facebook app. 
If i uninstall the facebook app, the authorization opens inside my application.

There's a way to open inside my application even with the Facebook app installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really not recommended because it is less secure and more of a hassle for users.  However it is still currently allowed for the time being.  In the Facebook.m file, change `authorizeWithFBAppAuth` to `NO` and `safariAuth` to `NO`:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO]
```